# Generate a code in sql after comparing with two table

Tags: c#, sql

I have two tables:

- Table A has a column `MainCode` which contain C18/02
- Table B has a column `Code` which contain C18/02/01

`MainCode` is bound to a dropdownlist.

When `MainCode` is selected, based on that selection, `Code` will be generated in a textbox.

Eg. C18/02 is selected in drop downlist, C18/02/01 will be generated in the textBox; if C18/02/01 is already in `Code`, C18/02/02 will be generated.

I need to do this using SQL, how do I do it?

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: im new to sql and its microsoft sql

Comment: "Microsoft SQL" as in ... Microsoft **SQL Server**, or SQL in Microsoft Access?? You're still not very clear .... please add a `sql-server` or `ms-access` tag accordingly - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assumming you selected the value `C18/02` from the main table you can select from the second table as in:

```
select * from table_b where code like 'C18/02' || '%';
```

The `'C18/02'` value is the value you retrieved from `table_a`. Easy!

Comment: There are a list of others selection is table A MainCode.

Comment: According to your question, no. There's only one value.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this, but this only covers 100 new codes for a given mainCode

```
Declare @mainCode varchar(100) = 'C18/02'
Select code = @mainCode + '/' + right('00'+convert(varchar(2),isnull((Select count(1) From table_b where code like @mainCode+'/%'),0)+1),2)
```

Comment: There are a list of others selection is table A MainCode.